# C# Winform Multithread sequence

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

Am relatively new to C# and coding in general. I am trying to write a program that has some logic and that also indicates progress with a progressbar. I am starting a thread in Main() that does all my business logic. It has events that are trigerred at points that I need the progress bar udpated.

The Form object subscribes to the business logic events and has thread safe delegates that are invoked to update the progress bars and text labels.

My problem is that, as the Form is started in the main thread, I have to start the business logic thread before Application.Run(). When the first ProgressUpdate event is trigerred, the Form object still does not exist. I guess a hacky way is to add Thread.Sleep(100) in the second thread, but I don't like that. How do I get around this? Am I on a completely incorrect track? (Am I even making sense?)

```
        Form1 theForm = new Form1();
        CreateReport theCreateReport = new CreateReport();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(theCreateReport.DoProcess));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        theForm.Subscribe(theCreateReport);
        t.Start();
        Application.Run(theForm);
```

theForm is the form. theCreateReport is where my business logic starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Form already exists after you invoke the constructor (on the very first line) - it's just not visible yet. So you don't need to worry, everything is initialized when you start the new thread.

Comment: That's why I split the constructor from what the default VC#S  project gave me. It doesn't seem to work though. Gives me an error that says that I shouldn't use Invoke/BeginInvoke before the object is created. If I put a try catch block with empty catch, it does work, but it feels like a hack. It could just be me being fussy.

Comment: It's a hack. Form-based applications in .Net are fundamentally built around the concept of a main form. There is no reason to fight this, as your project already uses a main form.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because, as Poma mentioned, the form did already exist. The error was in a different section of my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use one or more `BackgroundWorker` objects instead of your business logic thread. This will manage the threading for you as well as giving you a way to provide progress feedback to the main thread.

Comment: How different is that from starting my thread from within the Form1() method? I already have my handlers and delegates in place. Is it good programming practice to start off/do all the business logic from within the Form? Like I mentioned, am a complete newbie here. Thanks.

Comment: If you've already got something working, then by all means use it. BackgroundWorker just gives you an easy way of throwing a discrete task off to another thread and getting the result at a later time, without having to manage your own threading.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should start your business logic in OnLoad event?

Answer (score 0):

In `Main`, just create the form and `Application.Run` it.  In the `Load` event of the form, start your thread.

You don't really gain any advantage from doing things the way you're currently doing them.  And as you've already found, it creates a timing/sequence problem.

The best way to fix problems is to not have them in the first place.

Comment: I was told that it is good practice to completely decouple the GUI and business logic. (Instead of starting the Business Logic thread from within the GUI methods.) That did come from a Java developer I work with, though. So I don't know if it applies in the case of C# coding.

Comment: The separation of GUI and business logic has more to do with how your code is organized than with what threads the different objects are running on. Generally speaking, a multi-threaded application will be less reliable than a single-threaded one, since the pathways through your code come under the control of the thread scheduler and thus are less predictable. There are legitimate reasons that necessitate the inherent risks of multi-threading (and it *is* possible to do this safely if you know what you're doing), but conforming to the 3-tier orthodoxy really isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use BackgroundWorker and you can still use your events and delegates with it. This time round you will be wrapping up and firing Background Worker's "ProgressChanged" and "RunWorkerCompleted" events.

And you Form can listen to these events and update ProgressBar accordingly.

BWorker handles switching to GUI Thread and Exception Handling better.

You can initialize BackgroundWorker on Form Load.